# Would it be useful to let users organize their questions/answers by custom tags? (tags only seen by myself)

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tagging

I want a feature where I can organize my questions/answers in my math.stackexchange profile by some custom tags created and seen only by me. I want this feature because sometimes I forget which questions I did not fully understand / which answers I think may need some revisions after re-reading it many months/years after.

My current solution is to create an online note from other sites and copy-paste each of my questions/answers and use the custom tags feature provided there, but if someone had 500+ questions/answers this would become hard work! If the custom tags can be created and only seen by myself (so it won't affect other users), then I can create tags like: "Need revision", "Not fully understood", etc. and I can filter those that interest me, for example: "Not fully understood" + "linear algebra".

I'm not sure whether everyone will need this but personally I think this is a very good feature. What do you think about this idea?

Comment: The immediate concern that comes to my mind is that you describe an organizational system to fit *your personal organization wishes.*.  My personal organization wishes would look different from what you describe (e.g., I would like to organize into folders posts I bookmark) but would be no less valid than what you describe.  Still others have organization wishes that are different from yours and from mine.  So what exactly should the community request, in the form of a feature request, that meets the needs of those who wish some means to organize their own answers and questions?

Comment: @amWhy: I think I can create a third party plug-in/extension that fulfills our need, so people have the same interest can use it and the feature won't affect other users. Sorry for bad question...

Comment: It's not a *bad question*, and if might be helpful to have SE developers explore oranizational features, but it might be worth it to tag this post as a "discussion" rather than an immediate feature request, so that as a community, we can discuss a feature that might be helpful to most users, and fairly reasonable for developers to  implement (and might be of use to other users on other sites in the SE network, as well.)

Comment: @amWhy: Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: This feature request on [meta.se] is - to some extent - similar: [Favorites improvements - search, categorize, personal tags, add note, favorite answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75944).

Comment: @amWhy: I think there is a fairly user-agnostic feature request underlying FlyRain's request: User-specific tagging. I.e. each user can create tags that are 1) visible only to them, 2) unlimited in number and name, 3) can be applied to questions (and possibly answers), and 3) said tagging is visible only to the user that created them. Add to that the ability to filter by personal tags, and each user would be able to create their own personal organization, what ever it may be. I think this would be ... (cont.)

Comment: ... (cont.) would be powerful and very useful to a very small set of users. And as much as it appeals to me, I would probably down vote the proposal as requiring a whole lot of work for very small gain (when added up across all users of the site).

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC  But I want folders that I can custom name, to organize into folders according to the names I label them, all posts I answer.  Why should one user get catered to, and not others?  What you describe would also likely entail the capacity for a user to custom search using their personal tags, where my idea would allow me to open a folder, to open all relevant answers under that folders name.  Also note, that SE is notoriously known as a poor search engine!

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC  I think my feature preference is also user-agnostic.

Comment: @amWhy - Take a look at how Gmail uses "Labels" to emulate folders. In particular labels can take the form "Label1/SubLabelN", and you can treat these as a directory structure. I.e. what I am claiming is that tagging is strictly more powerful than directory trees. But I still don't think it would be a good use of resources by SE, and also have doubts about them doing it well.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC As I see it, tags are a flat structure.  Folders are hierarchical.  Your claim that tags are strictly more powerful than folders runs contrary to my intuition.